# SQL: Inner Join return one row based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, select, inner-join

This is probably simple, but i'm looking for the raw SQL to perform an `INNER JOIN` but only return one of the matches on the second table based on criteria.

Given two tables:

```
**TableOne**   
 ID  Name  
 1   abc  
 2   def

**TableTwo**  
 ID    Date     
 1     12/1/2014
 1     12/2/2014
 2     12/3/2014
 2     12/4/2014
 2     12/5/2014
```

I want to join but only return the latest date from the second table:

```
Expected Result:
1   abc   12/2/2014
2   def   12/5/2014
```

I can easily accomplish this in LINQ like so:

```
TableOne.Select(x=> new { x.ID, x.Name, Date = x.TableTwo.Max(y=>y.Date) });
```

So in other words, what does the above LINQ statement translate into in raw SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could join the first table with an aggregate query:

```
SELECT t1.id, d
FROM   TableOne t1
JOIN   (SELECT   id, MAX[date] AS d
        FROM     TableTwo
        GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Using `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`:

   ```
   SELECT one.ID,
          one.Name,
          MAX(two.Date)
       FROM TableOne one
           INNER JOIN TableTwo two on one.ID = two.ID
       GROUP BY one.ID, one.Name
   ```
2. Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) with a CTE:

   ```
   ; WITH cte AS (
       SELECT one.ID,
          one.Name,
          two.Date,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY one.ID ORDER BY two.Date DESC) as rn
       FROM TableOne one
          INNER JOIN TableTwo two ON one.ID = two.ID
   )
       SELECT ID, Name, Date FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT TableOne.id, TableOne.name, MAX(TableTwo.Date)
FROM TableOne
LEFT JOIN TableTwo ON TableOne.id = TableTwo.id
GROUP BY TableOne.id, TableOne.name;
```

The join will produce a table with as many rows as TableTwo, but the group by will filter it to one row per TableOne's rows.

Comment: I believe `using` doesn't work in SQL Server, it's specific to MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody else has covered a Common Table Expression (CTE) that will perform the task you want, I'll throw it in here:

```
with maxDates as (
    select Id, max(Date)
    from Table2
    group by Id
)
select x.Id, x.Name, y.Date
from TableOne x
inner join maxDates y
on x.Id = y.id
```